# How to find process doing very high io read (without iotop)

Tags: io, iostat

By using iostat I see a constant 200+MB/s read on a certain device. How can I understand on CentOS which process is causing this, without using iotop (I cannot install it in this environment)?

Comment: Maybe something like `watch -d 'grep -E "rchar: .{9}" /proc/[1-9]*/io'`? (also `read_bytes` instead of `rchar` for reads that eventually end up getting data off a block device).

Comment: If you can install [htop](http://hisham.hm/htop/), it has an option to show per process I/O rates.

Comment: @SatoKatsura unfortunately htop is not an option here

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas a bit intricate but works thank you.